# How to load Entities with an defined Graph in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have some problems with loading Entities in EF Core and not sure if I'm using it the wrong way or if this is a bug?

For Example:

```cs
public class Root 
{
   public Contained ContainedReference { get; set; }
}

public class Contained 
{
   public Contained AnotherContainedReference { get; set; }
   public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Root> Roots { get; set; } //Backreference
}
```

My Code to load the Entities looks like this:

```cs
    public override ICollection<Package> GetAll()
        {
            return Context.Set<Root>().Include(_=>_.ContainedReference);
        }
```

In my case now I want to load these Structure:
Root.ContainedReference

What I'm get is:
Root.ContainedReference.AnotherContainedReference

How I can tell EF Core that it should load Root including the ContainedReference but not the AnotherContainedReference in the ContainedReference?

If I now try to update (DBContext.Update(Root)) it will fail because there is an loop when iterating over the Contained.Roots and EF Core will throw something like

> The instance of entity type 'Root' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Because of the Backreferences (Roots in Contained, which shouldn't be loaded)

Thank you in advance

Chris

Comment: This is too complex for me. Could you cut it down to one question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @GertArnold I found this Extension somewhere on StackOverflow. There is an Include with one string. This is an Extension which aggregates the IEnumerable. Its also not working with the fluent API without the strings.

Comment: @bdongus my question is in the Subject. How can I load just that what I have defined, not more and not less.

Comment: @GertArnold Which code i should show you? The code is DBSet<Root>.Update() so I have the root object and I will just Update this object because I changed a property and the Update Method on DBSetwill throw because it finds the root object two times. First the object I put into the Update method, and the same instance in the Backreference List in the Contained Reference. Thats a very common and normal usecase so, no idea whats wrong.

Comment: @ChristianS. After you edited your original post I am less confused. Meanwhile you answered your own question. Unfortunately a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer on https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11564

I just clear the navigation properties for now it's working, but no end solution.
Maybe they will implement such a feature in the near future.